# Binary image in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, binary

How can I know if an image read with `imread` is binary in MATLAB

I did this :

```
Img = imread(IMGsrc);

T = Img== 1 | Img == 0;

If min(min(T)) == ??????

    imshow(T);

end
```

????? = ??????

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways you can test for binary images.

The simplest one is to test whether the image is a logical array (a logical array is returned by functions in the image processing toolbox that return binary image)

```
isBinaryImage = islogical(img);
```

Alternatively, you check whether all pixels are either 1 or 0

```
isBinaryImage = all( img(:)==0 | img(:)==1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by "binary" you mean "every pixel is either 1 or 0", a couple things given your image `I`:

- `size(I)` should only return rows and columns (not channels) otherwise it is not binary
- You can test every pixel is either `1` or `0` with `T = I == 1 | I == 0;`. If `min(min(T))` comes back anything but `1` then at least one pixel failed that test, meaning there is a value that is neither `0` nor `1`. (For that matter you could use a similar test to check for any number of enumerated values, not just `0` and `1`.)

If you can further clarify what you mean by "binary" that would go a long way to a better answer.

Comment: I'm trying to do this.

If Img is Binary Then ImgToBin = im2bw(Img); End If

I mean by binary (image with black and white colors).